# How to create a block of links shared by a user?

Tags: 7, views, navigation, media

I am using [oembed](https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed) to convert url to embedded content. I have enabled the oembed input filter in a text format. Now I want to create a block using views to only show the posts which have these links. How to do that?

Note: I want to use it on a custom form. Is there something which can detect embedded content in a view. By this I will be able to create a separate view/block containing the embedded content.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to make sure you've tried this simple approach. Create a check-box field for the all posts (whatever content-type it is) you were referring to with options embedded or non-embedded and create a view with a filter to only display embedded content.

Edit: Have a checkbox for the content-type (responsible for posts) which asks anyone creating posts if they are using the [oembed](https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed) text filter, give a description to check "embedded content" if they are.
Then create a view and pull all the posts by setting the filter- "CheckboxName (isOneOf) Embedded content".

Comment: I think I did not get you. As I have mentioned above, I am using text filter not field. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: See the edit. Hope I was clear this time

Comment: What if I am not using a content type? Actually I am using statuses module which is not an entity.